# Wrap elements inside another using classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to include two classes within a single class using jquery.

For some reasons i cant edit the html
For example Current html is

```
<div class="first">.....</div>
<div class="second">.....</div>
<div class="thrid">.....</div>
```

What i want is

```
<div class="MAIN-CLASS">
    <div class="first">.....</div>
    <div class="second">.....</div>
</div>
<div class="third">...</div>
```

I want to add MAIN-CLASS using Jquery

Comment: I'm a little unsure about what you're asking? "include two classes within a class"

Comment: every html element has a right to have class attribute.

Comment: @Aaron ...By that he meant...he has nested divisions and every division has a class attribute..is it possible?

Comment: please read it again ! i edited the question. 
I want to include two classes within a single class using jquery, for example Insert MAIN-CLASS that too with jquery

Comment: You have 2 inverted commas in `class="MAIN-CLASS""` ...So your class value is MAIN-CLASS".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of **[wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)** in jquery, see below code

```js
$(function(){
   $('.first, .second').wrapAll('<div class="MAIN_CLASS"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">.....first</div>
<div class="second">.....second</div>
<div class="thrid">.....thireed</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select the two classes by using:

```
$(".first, .second");
```

And then [`$.wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) them to that using:

```
$(".first, .second").wrapAll('<div class="MAIN-CLASS" />');
```

```js
$(function(){
   $('.first, .second').wrapAll('<div class="MAIN_CLASS"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">....</div>
<div class="second">....</div>
<div class="thrid">....</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("div").slice(0,2).wrapAll("<div class='MAIN-CLASS'></div>");
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pv5o4bLv/)

Comment: I think the `third` class is just for clarification purposes and thus should not be part of the final answer.